# How to validate duplicate file upload in Angular

Tags: angular

I have here my sample code to validate duplicate file.
This is my validation-service

I have import { filter, size } from 'lodash'

```
const duplicateFile = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'];
const filteredValues = filter(file, {name: duplicateFile});
const hasDuplicate = size(filteredValues) > 1;

if (hasDuplicate) { console.log ('duplicate') }
else { console.log('no duplicate') }
```

File - uploaded files

I tried this code but it's not working on my end.

Comment: what are these `filter` and `size` functions? from where you are importing it? What is the value of `file`? it is not declared in the lines you've posted.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how do you want yo check duplicated, by files names or it’s content. I understand you file contains some text inside.  If you are doing by name, so, you can simply do: duplicateFile.includes(file). It will give you true or false, if contains same value.

Comment: Oh I want to validate it by it's file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple>
```

```
selectedFiles: Array<File> = [];

onFileChange($event) {
  const fileList: FileList = $event.target.files;
  if (fileList.length > 0) {
    let files = Array.from(fileList);
    for (let item of files) {
      let existingItem = this.selectedFiles.find(x => x.name == item.name);
      if (!existingItem) {
        this.selectedFiles.push(item);
      } else {
        //validation error duplicate was found
      }
    }
  }
}
```